# Installing Atom editor on RedHat (Scientific) without root priviliges

Tags: terminal, software-installation, compiling, editors

I'm on the verge of giving up installing the atom editor on a university machine to which I don't have root access to. The instructions on the [Github page](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md) for building from source require some dependencies that need root access (*libgnome-keyring-dev*). An alternative suggested to me was to download the source code and try to compile it myself to a local directory. I'm finding it hard to get started on this however, because there are a large number of javascript files (I would appreciate any help on this). Any one with any suggestions or an easier way to do this?

Comment: Building from source requires root access, seriously? [Edit the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/230596/edit) and provide this link – It’s your job, not ours.

Comment: If building from source truly requires root, then you're better off finding a different editor written by a project team that doesn't do bad things (like require the build to be performed as root).

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Edited. (P.S: It wouldn't kill you to be polite)

Comment: It's written in javascript, and you should notice a shebang with something like `node` which stands for the nodejs executable in something like main.js. It's almost the same idea as other scripting languages here.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try unpacking, but not fully installing, the binary package
for your OS.  For example, I looked in the [releases](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.0.15)
dir and downloaded (with e.g. firefox, curl, or wget) the [64 bit rpm](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/download/v1.0.15/atom.x86_64.rpm)
for my Fedora 22, into a newly created directory, myatom, then unpacked it with

```
cd myatom
rpm2cpio x86_64.rpm | cpio -cid
```

and ran

```
~/myatom/usr/bin/atom
```

and it seemed to work.

Comment: Extract and run is having this error: [14412:0111/124727.124898:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that [...]/share/atom/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
Trace/BPT trap

Comment: Things have probably changed after 5 years. You should post a new question referring back to this question and saying what happened.